# Different between native C code run in jni and run in the shell in Android

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface, native

I have a native C Android application. First I build native C code into shared library and jni will use this library. This library uses some kernel loadable module .ko, some already loaded, some must loaded by "insmod" command.

I also build an executable that use this library and it run ok by command line. But the jni which do the same work as executable run fail when it calls function that need kernel module to be loaded.

So what is the difference between them? Do I need grant some permission for my app?

Comment: In this case, the JNI builds a shared library, which is not an independent executable. It just contains classes and methods that will be used in the app. The executable you build is literally an "executable". It has its own entry point and becomes a separate process when called from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your device is rooted.

> I also build an executable that use this library and it run ok by command line.

Maybe you run this command with `su` and can execute it without issue.

But, if you execute your binary from App by JNI, then you are actually running the command with a normal user permission which may have issue if your C code invokes some kernel functions.

Have you tried below code in your app?

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su").
```

Here is some reference for you http://muzikant-android.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-get-root-access-and-execute.html?_sm_au_=iqsHGF7FqZfPGrJb

Comment: Thanks for your help. My situation is exactly the same as you think. I tried using Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su") and also added <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER"/> to manifest but I have an issue with permission denied. My device is rooted.

Comment: I also checked that, my app run with user "u0_a41" instead "root" as I do with executable in command line. So your answer is right, seem it doesn't have permission to invokes kernel function.

Comment: @NVDQ, Could you please vote up my answer and accept it if it helped you? Thanks.